# Recognise tool by which file was encrypted

Tags: cryptography, file-encryption

I have file with extension *.encrypted. Can you give me some advice how to recognise by witch tool was this file encrypted? It´s not encrypted by some ransomware but by some encrypt tool. When I open the file using a notepad, I can see this: `M%Ý~ÝÀ©üŒ]ÏùfB€d€N¯à’ßÌ•¤Ü]ñåo`

Comment: Any private and custom encryption tool can generate `*.encrypted` file as output. I personally have created a custom file encryptor which uses AES and generates `*.exe.encrypted` as output. So it isn't necessarily an public and famous tool.

Comment: this is a duplicate of: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/197541/encrypted-file-i-need-decrypt-it

Comment: Asking what application is the wrong approach, you should be asking what is the algorithm used. Likely they used some form of standard encryption, though it is possible it is a homegrown algorithm. It is your task to analyze the file (as binary, not text), and reverse engineer it. What you're asking is not a trivial task.

Answer (score 3):

Unless the application encryption sticks "something" (header, a magic token, etc...) on the header in general it is not possible to know which was the application that makes the encryption.

Comment: Would it help if I send you that file?